# I want to get property value from code behind

Tags: asp.net

I have a case that I need to set the Text property for an asp label in the aspx page not from code behind. More exactly, I need to set a value to asp control in aspx page and this value is set by a property in the same page code behind.

so I need to use an expression to do that like:

```
<asp:Label Text="<%= MyProperty %>" ..../>
```

I use:

```
<%= MyProperty %> doesn't work.
<%# MyProperty %> doesn't also.
```

Comment: When you debug, do you see if "MyProperty" is getting set in the code behind?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Default.aspx.cs

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public string CustomTitle = "This Is Title";

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Page.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Default.aspx

```
<asp:Label Text='<%#CustomTitle %>' runat="server" />
```

Comment: it's work but and it write the value on the page as html span but not work if I use it inside the label tag !!

Answer (score 15):

You have to treat regular HTML and WebControls differently:

---

**regular HTML**:

Using `<%= ... %>` is sufficient:

```
<span><%= MyProperty %></span>
```

---

**WebControls** (stuff starting with <asp:...>):

```
<asp:Label Text='<%# MyProperty %>' />
```

In this case, you also have to call `Me.DataBind()` (VB) or `this.DataBind();` (C#) in your codebehind, since `<%# ... %>` are data binding expressions.

Comment: I do call to this.DataBind in page load but dosen't work with me !!?

Comment: <%= ... %> doesn't work for me in a head section which has runat="server" set. The output source shows <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/custom.css?v=&lt;%=CSSVersionVal%>" media="screen" /> instead of <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/custom.css?v=2" media="screen" />. I have CSSVersionVal set as a Property in the codebehind and it's outputting correctly everywhere else in the page, but not in the head.

Answer (score 5):

```
Page.DataBind();
```

Do you call this in your code? It binds all variables set in code to your page.