# Assign server side variable as a text of textbox

Tags: asp.net

`Rank` is my server side variable.

I am trying this

```
<asp:TextBox ID="sds" runat="server" Text="<%# Eval(Rank) %>"></asp:TextBox>
```

But there comes nothing in text box, however when I write the same on response stream, it gives me result.

```
<%= Rank %>
```

I tried without `Eval` also.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="sds" runat="server" Text="<%# Rank %>">
```

Why it's coming null when assigned to textbox?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this `<asp:TextBox />` nested inside a listview, repeater, etc?

Comment: Nope. That's why I tried without eval.

Comment: Can't you access the TextBox on `Page_Load`? (i.e. `sds.Text = Rank;`)

Comment: @zgood it's just POC. Want to do this way

Comment: How is `Rank` declared?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
Text='<%# Bind("rank") %>'
```

For example:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="sds" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("rank") %>'  ></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding

```
this.DataBind();
```

to your page load? Referenced from article [Get variable value from code behind and use in aspx page control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8883262/get-variable-value-from-code-behind-and-use-in-aspx-page-control)

The other answers above are also acceptable but you need to choose your method or preference and the context/method your data is being generated and referenced into (Controls, plain HTML, etc...).

HTH

Dave