# How to add a css class to <i> element based on a condition(value from code behind) using javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, .net

I want to add a css class (fontawesome classes) to the `<i>` element based on the file type which is found from the code behind.

I'm trying to achieve something like this. (so that the font changes based on the file type from code behind)
[image]

I tried to write a JS function which I thought would solve the problem.

```
        <head>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                    function showIcon() {
                        if(<%#Eval("fileType")%>=="ppt" || <%#Eval("fileType")%> =="pptx")
                        {
                            document.getElementById('icon').className = 'fa fa-file-powerpoint-o  fa-3x';
                        }
                        else if(<%#Eval("fileType")%>=="doc" || <%#Eval("fileType")%> =="docx")
                        {
                            document.getElementById('icon').className = 'fa fa-file-word-o  fa-3x';
                        }
                    }
                </script>
            </head>

        <body>
            <div class="col-xs-1">
                                <h3><td><%# Eval("count") %></td></h3>
                                <span>match</span>
                                <div id="icon"><i aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                            </div>
        </body>
```

Can someone help me to correct this. Is there any other way in which I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Check your page source in your browser, but I'd guess that the line:

```
if(<%#Eval("fileType")%>=="ppt" || <%#Eval("fileType")%> =="pptx")
```

is being output as

```
if(ppt=="ppt" || ppt =="pptx")
```

into your html.

Try wrapping the Eval into '...' marks

```
    if('<%#Eval("fileType")%>'=="ppt" || '<%#Eval("fileType")%>' =="pptx")
```

Comment: It is showing something like in page source. I think its not correctly giving the Eval property. `if(''=="ppt" || '' =="pptx")`

Answer (score 0):

Any HTML Element has a property called `classList`. You can access the contents like you would with an array (`element.classList[0]`) and add or remove elements with `add`, `remove` and `toggle`.

[Mozilla Developer Article about the classList Property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

Comment: Looks like I didn't recognise your problem. I'd still like to leave this answer for future visitors

Answer (score 0):

Try

`<%= fileType %>` instead of `<%# Eval("fileType") %>`

Make sure fileType is public

Please refer this link
[I want to get property value from code behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5548812/i-want-to-get-property-value-from-code-behind)

Comment: CS0103: The name 'fileType' does not exist in the current context error

Comment: Change to property with public/protected access specifier
BTW is that a field right ?

Comment: `public string fileType { get; set; }` This is how it is defined.

Comment: Try to check the code or debug whether the value is being assigned properly

Comment: More important you should call Page.DataBind(); in page load event

Answer (score 0):

A bit improvement on your JS because we shouldnt mix server side code and client code as much as possible

```
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    function showIcon(fileType) {
                        if(fileType ==="ppt" || fileType ==="pptx")
                        {
                            document.getElementById('icon').className = 'fa fa-file-powerpoint-o  fa-3x';
                        }
                        else if(fileType ==="doc" || fileType === "docx")
                        {
                            document.getElementById('icon').className = 'fa fa-file-word-o  fa-3x';
                        }
                    }
                </script>
                <div class="col-xs-1">
                            <h3><td><%# Eval("count") %></td></h3>
                            <span>match</span>
                            <div id="icon"><i aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                        </div>
```

If you use Jquery 
run with

```
$(function(){
  showIcon('<%#Eval("fileType")%>');
});
```

If you are not using Jquery 
write function another javascript function

```
function yourFunctionName(){
  showIcon('<%#Eval("fileType")%>');
}
```

Then Call yourFunctionName in body .onLoad

```
<body onload="yourFunctionName()">
```

Because the server side data render first and it will also render <%#Eval("fileType")%> first then client side js functions will execute when the server side rendering complete.

[here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp) is ref for onload

Hope it would help :)

Comment: Actually the entire code is inside a repeater and so the filetype changes from one repeater item to another. so I dont think body onload will be helpful . Am I correct?

Comment: I dont get your 'repeater'.As my understanding  if your 'repeater' means iteration from server side script. It will work on body onload. Because it is Javascript onload event will called after your iteration from server side script.