# <% %> tags sometimes work, sometimes don't

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have some user controls in my .NET web application, I'm using them in the same page. They have some properties and for some reason I need some hidden fields that hold the values of the properties.

So in one of the user controls there's this piece of code:

```
<input type="hidden" data-versus="PL"  value="<%= vs_pl %>" />
```

Where vs_pl is the property of the control:

```
private decimal? _vs_pl; // plan
public decimal? vs_pl {
    get { return _vs_pl; }
    set { _vs_pl = value; }
}
```

All this is rendered correctly as this:

```
<input type="hidden" data-versus="PL" value="-190.2">
```

In the other user control I have a similar piece of code:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hfOrg" runat="server" Value='<%= org %>' />
```

Where org is a property similar to the above one. But this is rendered as:

```
<input type="hidden" name="ctl00$cs$hfOrg" id="cs_hfOrg" value="<%= org %>">
```

In the very same page. None of the two controls have data binding or data controls internally and they are not bound to a data source in the page either.

I realize that the first case is not a server control, just a normal HTML input tag, while the latter is rendered by the server. However I find this a strange behavior and I'd expect it to work in the second case too.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I want to get property value from code behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5548812/i-want-to-get-property-value-from-code-behind)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<%= %>` Is a shortcut for Response.Write and it will only work in plain HTML like here

```
<input type="hidden" data-versus="PL"  value="<%= vs_pl %>" />
```

You should use DataBindings in server controls like this

```
<input type="hidden" name="ctl00$cs$hfOrg" id="cs_hfOrg" value="<%# org %>">
```

It's important to remember that if you use DataBindings you should call the UserControl's `DataBind` method directly or indirectly but calling the `DataBind` method of a parent control or the Page itself.

Reference:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6dwsdcf5(VS.71).aspx
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bda9bbfx(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: The thing I find strange is that <%= works in HTML without data binding, while doesn't work with a server control, even if the variable I'm trying to bind to is available and not data source-related, so data binding is not necessary. As it isn't in the HTML case. I find it highly illogical.

Comment: It's because of the ASP.NET parser, long story for a comment. Lets say that ASP.NET has a Regex looking for elements with runat="server" when it finds matches it will inject there there Control.Render() output (so a <%=%> will never be processed) elements without runat="server" will be ignored and then all the `<%=%>` will be processed in those elements. A simple `runat="server"` changes many things

Answer (score 1):

When you are trying to bind data in a Control you need another syntax.

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hfOrg" runat="server" Value='<%# org %>' />
```

And if that control is outside a Repeater/GridView etc you need to call `DataBind()` in Page_Load.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataBind();
}
```

Comment: But none of them are bound to data sources. I don't need data binding - at least not yet.

Comment: Yes you do, otherwise the value of `org` is not bound to the Control. Try the above code with and without `DataBind()` and you'll see that there is no value inside `hfOrg` even though you used `<%# org %>`

Comment: I think I understand what you're trying to say, I've used data binding expressions a gazillion times before.

What I'm trying to say is that we are in the same aspx page, we have similar control properties and the same shorthand (<%= property %>) for the same attribute (value) of fundamentally the same kind of control (a hidden field) works once but doesn't work 10 lines below that. Only because one is a html control, the other is a server control.

Comment: server controls and plain html are NOT the same from a webform perspective. Only when the page is rendered to the browser will the server controls be rendered as html.